# Compare 2 arrays in Scala Spark Dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, intersect

I have a dataframe with 2 columns of Array[String] like this :

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        HEURE_USAGE|        LISTE_CODE_1|        LISTE_CODE_2|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|2019-09-06 11:34:57|[GBF401, GO0421, ...|[GB9P01, GO2621, ...|
|2019-09-02 13:27:49|[GO1180, BTMF01, ...|[GO3180, OLMP01, ...|
|2019-09-02 13:17:53|[GO1180, BTMF01, ...|[GO1180, BTMF01, ...|
|2019-09-06 11:27:05|[GBF401, GO0421, ...|[GBX401, GO0721, ...|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I'm trying to create a column `'LISTE_CODE_3'` that would be the intersection of the column `'LISTE_CODE_1'` and the column `'LISTE_CODE_2'` for each row.

There is a perfect function that does this in Spark 2.4.

It is the intersect function that returns the intersection without duplication.
Unfortunately, this feature does not exist in Spark 2.2.

I think maybe we should compare sets.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a user-defined function:

```scala
spark.udf.register("intersect_arrays", (a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String]) => a intersect b)
spark.sql("select *, intersect_arrays(LISTE_CODE_1, LISTE_CODE_2) as LISTE_CODE_3 from ds")
```

Or do it in pure Spark SQL (assuming here that `HEURE_USAGE` is unique across the dataset):

```scala
spark.sql("""
   select ds.HEURE_USAGE, LISTE_CODE_1, LISTE_CODE_2, coalesce(inter, array()) as LISTE_CODE_3
   from ds left join (
     select HEURE_USAGE, collect_list(CODE_1) as inter from (
       select * from (
         select HEURE_USAGE, CODE_1, explode(LISTE_CODE_2) as CODE_2
         from (select HEURE_USAGE, explode(LISTE_CODE_1) as CODE_1, LISTE_CODE_2 as LISTE_CODE_2 from ds)
       ) where CODE_1 = CODE_2
   ) group by HEURE_USAGE) t
   on t.HEURE_USAGE = ds.HEURE_USAGE""")
```

The idea is to explode `LISTE_CODE_1` and `LISTE_CODE_2`, to keep only the rows that have a matching `CODE_1` and `CODE_2`, to collect the `CODE`s into a new array, and to join with the original dataframe to keep all the original rows (even those where the intersection is empty).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I think UDF is perfect for me, but I have an error when I execute.  
I tried with :  
val intersectArray = udf((a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String]) => a intersect b)  
val test: DataFrame = dfVoixJoinGroupedWithUse
  .withColumn("LISTE_CODE_3", intersectArray(col("LISTE_CODE_1"), col("LISTE_CODE_2")))  
I think that's right but I have an error  
Any idea ?  
Thank

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sachav.
It's OK, it works perfect.
Thank a lot for your help.
Have a nice day.